# select , distinct is not working in sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

I was working in sailsjs a few day ago.

I just can't figure it out why my sailsjs app doesn't support select or distinct it says that this is not defind .

Am I missing something?

Please someone help me to figure this out.

I try this

```
Blog.find().select('keyfield').sort('createdAt DESC').done(function(err, selectedKeyfield) {
              res.view('home/index',{
              Keyfield: selectedKeyfield
        });
```

Thank you in advance....

Comment: Just to clarify: is 'mysql' the adapter you are using?

Comment: no i am using sails mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the stable version of Sails, which is now something like `0.9.x`, then `.select()` nor `.distinct()` haven't been introduced yet.

Here's the open requests for `.distinct()`:
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/60
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/pull/55

Here's the issue about using projection with sorting, which will give you a hint on how to emulate `.select()`:
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/53

Comment: thanks dude . it is so late but thanks for your ans i am now using sails 0.10